# Deleting file after upload

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file with the FileUpload control. When file is uploaded, I extract information from it and then i want to delete it.

I manage to upload it, save it and get the info from it, but when i try to delete it i get the follwing exception
"The process cannot access the file 'D:\IIS***OMITTED****\V75 personal ny.csv' because it is being used by another process.

```
 string fn = Path.GetFileName(fu.PostedFile.FileName);
        string SaveLocation = Server.MapPath("UploadedCSVFiles") + "\\" + fn;
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(SaveLocation);

            fu.PostedFile.SaveAs(SaveLocation);
            fu.PostedFile.InputStream.Dispose();
            DataTable dt = AMethodThatUsesFile(SaveLocation);
            fi.Delete();
```

Comment: We probably need to know what's in AMethodThatUsesFile()

Comment: You specified a method AMethodThatUsesFile(SaveLocation);. If it uses any classes like StreamReader to read file, please close the reader using StreamReader.Close(); method before trying to delete

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this code to delete file.

```
            System.IO.File.Delete(SaveLocation );
```

You specified a method AMethodThatUsesFile(SaveLocation);. If it uses any classes like StreamReader to read file, please close the reader using StreamReader.Close(); method before trying to delete

Comment: There's no apparent reason he should need to check for the file's presence here; the error indicates the file certainly *does* exist, as expected. The trouble likely resides in the aforementioned (and not included) method.

Answer (score 1):

dispose the `fi` before deleting. and then us `File.Delete()`. remember to use using statements when use disposable objects, or dispose it after use.

Comment: Does FileInfo even implement IDisposable?

Comment: @Chamika Sandamal no this is not it. I have tried that already.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.io

 File.Delete(Server.MapPath("../Nurturing/" + fnevents));
            FileInfo fInfoEvent;
            fInfoEvent = new FileInfo(fnevents);
            fInfoEvent.Delete();
```

here **fnevents** is the name of the file that u are deleting. **Nurturing** is the name of the folder.