# System.IO.IOException on delete image

Tags: c#, asp.net

I get the error "An exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll ...
Additional information: The process cannot access the file  because it is being used by another process.

I have a panel of images from which to choose the image in the main frame, and a button on the main frame to delete the image. I can delete any image from the panel except the last one to be uploaded.
Here's the upload code:

```
fulImages.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(fileName));

Bitmap thumb = new Bitmap(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath(fileName)), new Size(200, 150));
thumb.Save(Server.MapPath(thumbName));
thumb.Dispose();
System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath(fileName)).Dispose();
fulImages.PostedFile.InputStream.Dispose();
```

As you can see, I dispose of everything I can think of, yet I still get the exception. The delete process is simply:

```
File.Delete(MapPath(imgMain.ImageUrl));
File.Delete(MapPath(flip));
```

the "flip" variable is the downloaded image URL and imgMain.ImageURL is the thumbnail image URL. The error occurs on the File.Delete(MapPath(flip)) line. Can anyone tell what's happening here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deleting file after upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8006903/deleting-file-after-upload)

Comment: Check that fulImages.PostedFile.SaveAs closes the file the image is saved to.